# 'stdio.h' File Not Found When Compiling Hello World

Tags: c, xcode, macos, compiler-errors, include

Edit: added output of `$cc -v main.c` at the end of this post.

I'm using an old Xcode because my kernel extension will support El Capitan.  That works with 8.3 by copying the 10.11 SDK from an older Xcode build.

```
#include <stdio.h>   // 'stdio.h' file not found

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
   printf( "Hello World!\n" );

   return 0;
}

$ ls -l /usr/include/stdio.h
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  19154 Feb  4  2017 /usr/include/stdio.h

$ ls -l /Applications/Xcode_8.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
-r--r--r--  7 mike  staff  19154 Feb  3  2017 /Applications/Xcode_8.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
```

I'm trying to build a userspace command line tool to test my kernel extension.

This is a moderately common problem but none of the solutions I've tried so far have worked.  There are lots of reports of it happening in Visual Studio, not just Xcode.

Just now I reinstalled the Command Line Tools.  I changed the SDK from "latest macOS" to "macOS 10.12".

The source file is called "main.c" - that is, *not* "main.cpp".

```
$ cc -v main.c
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode_8.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

"/Applications/Xcode_8.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.12.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -target-linker-version 278.4 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode_8.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.1.0 -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/mike/Projects/RCI/trunk/HD1/ButtonTest -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.12.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/xc/jc2d96hx25l9ntd2vgnh124m0000gn/T/main-7206a2.o -x c main.c
clang -cc1 version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42) default target x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/Applications/Xcode_8.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.1.0/include
/Applications/Xcode_8.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
/usr/include
/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.

"/Applications/Xcode_8.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library

/Applications/Xcode_8.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -o a.out
/var/folders/xc/jc2d96hx25l9ntd2vgnh124m0000gn/T/main-7206a2.o -lSystem

/Applications/Xcode_8.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.1.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

Comment: Try printing the GCC include path?

Comment: This has to be some kind of installation problem.  We need some more diagnostic information.  Run the command `cc -v main.c`, and edit the _complete and unedited_ output of that command into your question, please.

Comment: Check your installation — there is something wrong.  Maybe running `xcode-select` will help: `xcode-select -h` gives help, `xcode-select -p` gives you path information, and `xcode-select --install` installs/configures XCode.  Given that you have `/usr/include/stdio.h` on disk, it is a bit surprising that you're getting 'not found', but that means the compiler must be looking elsewhere.

Comment: zwol - "gcc main.c" builds "a.out" if I run it from the command line.  It's only from within the IDE that it can't find <stdio.h>.

Comment: The problem may be caused by Xcode being in a folder so I can install multiple versions.  But I've been doing that for years without such trouble.  "/Applications/Xcode_8.3/Xcode.app"

Comment: The other target in the same Xcode project is a kernel extension.  It's got lots of #include lines but compiles just fine.

Comment: If I rename the source to "main.cpp" then "#include <ostream>" and "#include <iostream>" don't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Should Not Drink And Code:

My project had at first just one target, for a kernel extension.  Later I added a second target for a command-line tool.

When I created a new source file for my command-line tool that source somehow got added to the kernel extension's target.  Changing the tool's header search path settings had no effect on my problem because the source was not in the tool's target.

Kernel Extensions - device drivers - have headers that are only from Kernel.framework, in which there is no stdio.h file.

I'll shut up now.